# Foursquare authentication asks user to open app

Tags: android, foursquare

For my mobile web application I'd like users to authorize my Foursquare app, so I redirect them to

> https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=token&redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI

Then, when the user tries to login on this page on Android, it prompts a 'complete action using' dialog, twice(!), where the users has to choose between the browser and the Foursquare app. When you try to login with the Foursquare app, though, nothing happens...

Is there a way to stop this behaviour on Android?

Answer (score 0):

Embed the webview inside of your application. See https://github.com/foursquare/android-oauth-example as an official reference.

Comment: I might have been clearer, but I'm developing a mobile website running in the browser, so this isn't really a solution, unfortunately.

Comment: Hrm, there's no way for you to control this, but if the android app is intercepting that URL, that's a bug. Will contact the team about it.